# Powershell Jobs with SharePoint Connection

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

(Basic desire is to cascade delete files. Also, use the same concept to recurse copy files to SharePoint)

How do you pass a SharePoint connection into a PowerShell job.

If I use `Connect-PNPOnline -ReturnConnection` and then pass the variable into the Job as an argument I get the following error.

```
System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException: Cannot bind parameter 'Connection'. Cannot convert the "SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.SPOnlineConnection" value of type "Deserialized.SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.SPOnlineConnection" to type "SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.SPOnlineConnection". ---> System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidCastException: Cannot convert the "SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.SPOnlineConnection" value of type "Deserialized.SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.SPOnlineConnection" to type "SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.SPOnlineConnection".
   at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ThrowInvalidCastException(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType)
   at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ConvertNoConversion(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType, Boolean recurse, PSObject originalValueToConvert, IFormatProvider formatProvider, TypeTable backupTable)
   at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ConversionData`1.Invoke(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType, Boolean recurse, PSObject originalValueToConvert, IFormatProvider formatProvider, TypeTable backupTable)
   at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType, Boolean recursion, IFormatProvider formatProvider, TypeTable backupTypeTable)
   at System.Management.Automation.ParameterBinderBase.CoerceTypeAsNeeded(CommandParameterInternal argument, String parameterName, Type toType, ParameterCollectionTypeInformation collectionTypeInfo, Object currentValue)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

**Without** passing in the argument I get the following error.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No connection, please connect first
   with Connect-PnPOnline    at
   SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.PnPCmdlet.BeginProcessing()    at
   SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.PnPWebCmdlet.BeginProcessing()    at
   System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoBeginProcessing()    at
   **strong text**System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoBegin()
```

I understand that PowerShell jobs work in their own scope but I just cannot figure out how to pass in the connection information.

Here is my code snippet

```
Clear-Host
$z=$files.Count
Foreach($file in $files){

    $jobs = @(Get-Job -State Running)

    If($jobs.Count -le 15){
        $null=$jobs|Wait-Job -Any
    }

    $SB={
        $SBListName = $args[0]
        $FileID = $args[1]
        $FileName = $args[2]
        $LogPath=$args[3]

        Try{
            Remove-PnPListItem -Connection $args[4] -list $SBListName -Identity $FileID -Force -ErrorAction Stop

            $LogStatus = 'COMPLETE'
            $LogMessage = 'File Removed'

        } catch {
            $LogStatus = 'ERROR'
            $LogMessage = $_.exception

        } Finally {
            # Log action
            $line = [pscustomobject]@{
                'DateTime' = (Get-Date)
                'Item Type'="File"
                'Item ID'=$FileID
                'Item Name'=$FileName
                'Message' = $LogMessage
                'Status' = $LogStatus
            }

            $line | Export-Csv -Path $LogPath  -Append -NoTypeInformation
        }
    }
    $fileName = $File.fieldValues['FileLeafRef']
    $FileID = $file.Id
    Write-Host "($z) - $fileName"
    $null=Start-Job -Name $fileName -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList $SPOListName, $FileID, $fileName, $SBLogPath, $connection
    $z--
}
```